# GROUP_CONCAT and join, how to include not matching rows also

Tags: mysql, group-concat

How to include non matching rows in `GROUP_CONCAT` ? Here, Table `cls_sec` contains each section assigned to class.

Class **One** has **2** **section** - '**A**' and '**B**',

Class **Two** has **1 Section** '**A**'

Class **Three** has **No** section.

Here section is key to join relation between tables, but how can I include **class three** which has no section in `GROUP_CONCAT` result.

Table `cls` - lists of Class

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   One
2   |   Two
3   |   Three
```

Table `sec` - lists of section

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   A
2   |   B
```

Table `cls_sec` - lists of each section assigned to Class

```
id  |   c_id|   s_id    
=====================
1   |   1   |   1
2   |   1   |   2
3   |   2   |   1
```

According to rows in `cls_sec`, my expectation is as below,

```
1.One-B,1.One-A,2.Two-A,3.Three
```

if class has section, each section will display with its associated class, **else** echo only class (if any section hasn't assigned to this class) :

So what I do in mysql select if matched rows OR null rows

**MySQL CODE**

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cls.id,'.',cls.en_ttl, '-', sec.en_ttl 
                 ORDER BY cls.id) AS cls
FROM
    cls
LEFT JOIN
    cls_sec ON cls_sec.c_id = cls.id
JOIN
    sec ON sec.id = cls_sec.s_id OR cls_sec.s_id is NULL 
ORDER BY cls.id DESC
```

But I am getting

```
1.One-B,1.One-A,2.Two-A,3.Three-B,3.Three-A
```

Comment: Usage of `order by` at the end is not required, when you are aggregating everything into one row.

Comment: Can you provide `Create Table` statements as well ? Or a SQL fiddle / DB Fiddle. This helps in quicker testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Join` with `OR .. IS NULL` condition needs to be replaced with `LEFT JOIN`.
- There is no need of `ORDER BY` at the end, when you are aggregating into one row.
- Use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to consider the case when there is no section for a class.
- I have added [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function inside the `Group_concat()`, for ease of understandability. However, as [suggested by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119563/group-concat-and-join-how-to-include-not-matching-rows-also/53119651?noredirect=1#comment93133906_53119651) *@Raymond Nijland*, we can still work without using it.
- `Concat()` function returns `null`, if any of the substrings to concatenate is `null`. So, when there is no section, we will need to move `-` into `Concat()`, to avoid any trailing `-` in the string.

Try:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cls.id,'.',cls.en_ttl, 
                        COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.en_ttl), ''))  
                 ORDER BY cls.id) AS cls
FROM
    cls
LEFT JOIN
    cls_sec ON cls_sec.c_id = cls.id
LEFT JOIN
    sec ON sec.id = cls_sec.s_id
```

Comment: Query seams ok +1 but "You were missing Concat() function inside the Group_concat()." it's not really needed GROUP_CONCAT kinda works like CONCAT with string concatenation see this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpriwCHK4aZqTHH4NX6iFL/1 but i would advice using `CONCAT` when using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland (facepalm) - MySQL and its ever-increasing list of shorthand tricks :-| ; Thanks for the tip. I will edit my explanation, but I would prefer to keep the usage of `Concat()` , as it makes code easy to understand.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Thanks man !, had not idea about `COALESCE`  before, got new topic to learn.

Comment: @AnandHmt  happy to help :) Additional tip:- MySQL provides couple more functions similar to `Coalesce()` : `Ifnull()` and `NullIf()`. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html